# AjaxForm submit without file gives 500 Error

Tags: jquery, file, upload, ajaxform

I have jQuery AjaxForm working if I attach file while submit , But without attaching file its not able to submit and it gives 500 error. I am using Spring for backend on apache tomcat.

```
{jQuery('#newSchoolForm').ajaxForm({

              type: "POST",

              async:false,
              url: 'newSchool.do?action=save',
                mimeType:"multipart/form-data",
                processData: false, 
                contentType:false,
              success: function(data)
                {
```

```
              $('#errorMsg').append("<li>"+data+"</li>");

            },  
          error: function(e)
            {   $('#errorMsg').append(e.responseText);
                $('#errorMsg').append("<li>Unexpected Error .Please Try again later.</li>");
            }  
                 }).submit();

    }
        });}
```

And my form is like below , I am calling above ajax on button click:

```
    <form:form action="" modelAttribute="newSchoolContractForm" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="newSchoolContractForm">
    <table>
    <tr>
    <td><label for="">Date : </label></td>
    <td><form:input path="startDate" id="startDate" title="StartDate" />   </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td><label for="">Attachment</label></td>
    <td><input type="file" name="file" id="file"/></td>
    </tr>
    </table>
    </form>
```

Comment: You need to look at the server log to findout what is the cause of the error

Comment: 500 means Internal Server Error. There should be a stacktrace in the server error log.

Comment: don't ever use `async:false` . it blocks all other code running and is being deprecated by browser vendors

Comment: @Arun : At Server Side I am not able to see any logs .. Nothing !! just in e.responseText at browser side I am getting 500.

Comment: @ViralPatel there is nothing much we can do in the client side without knowing what is happening in the server